# How to call function in sql server with entity framework

Tags: entity-framework-6

No idea how to do this;

The client I work for has a database with functions (not stored procedures!) that have a lot of complex logic that we must use since there is no time to reproduce them in C# code. We use database first.

I honestly don't know where to start! I have added the function with "Update the Model" via the edmx, and I see the function appear in the storage section of the xml configuration.

But now? With stored procedures, EF creates methods in the context class. But apparently not so with functions. I do not know what to do from here. Do I manually add a method for the function in this context class?

Please help!

Comment: One way is to create a stored procedure that implement the function.

Comment: I now try to do it with `context.Database.SqlQuery`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling user defined functions in Entity Framework 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3500509/calling-user-defined-functions-in-entity-framework-4)

Comment: What about duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27008369/calling-db-function-with-entity-framework-6